System.MissingMethodException when trying to use LLamaSharp in a tool window
I've been playing around with LlamaSharp. Got it working in a console and a Windows Form so far. Currently I am trying to implement a model into a tool window extension. However, when I try to open said window, I get the following error:

System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Void LLama.LLamaContext..ctor(LLama.LLamaWeights, LLama.Abstractions.IContextParams, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger)'.'

I assume it has something to do with making the LlamaContext. This is what my code for the tool window looks like:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using LLama;
using LLama.Abstractions;
using LLama.Common;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.Internal;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;

namespace CodeAssist
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ChatBotControl.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ChatBotControl : UserControl
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ChatBotControl"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// 

        private readonly string _modelPath;
        private readonly ModelParams _parameters;
        private readonly LLamaWeights _model;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly InteractiveExecutor _executor;
        private readonly ChatHistory _chatHistory;
        private readonly ChatSession _session;
        private readonly InferenceParams _inferenceParams;

        public ChatBotControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            _modelPath = @"codellama-7b.Q3_K_L.gguf";
            _parameters = new ModelParams(_modelPath)
            {
                ContextSize = 1024,
                GpuLayerCount = 5,
            };
            _model = LLamaWeights.LoadFromFile(_parameters);

            var loggerFactory = new Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory();
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<InteractiveExecutor>();
            var contextParams = _parameters;

            var context = new LLamaContext(_model, _parameters, _logger);
            _executor = new InteractiveExecutor(context);



            _chatHistory = new ChatHistory();
            _chatHistory.AddMessage(AuthorRole.System, "Transcript of a dialog, where the User interacts with an Assistant named Bob. Bob is helpful, kind, honest, good at writing, and never fails to answer the User's requests immediately and with precision.");
            _chatHistory.AddMessage(AuthorRole.User, "Hello, Bob.");
            _chatHistory.AddMessage(AuthorRole.Assistant, "Hello. How may I help you today?");
            _session = new ChatSession(_executor, _chatHistory);
            _inferenceParams = new InferenceParams()
            {
                MaxTokens = 256,
                AntiPrompts = new List<string> { "User:" }
            };
        } 
    }
}


based on the docs https://github.com/SciSharp/LLamaSharp it should be using var context = model.CreateContext(parameters);
